# How have toggle dropdown on button click and close on outside click?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have Dropdown which is open by clicking on button and closed on outside click.

This is function which toggle dropdown:

```
toggleAllCategories = () => {
  this.setState({ isOpenAllCategories: !this.state.isOpenAllCategories });
};
```

That mean by clicking on button you should open and close Dropdown.

But in same time I have implemented with `react-refs` that click outside of body of dropdown ---> close dropdown.

That make bug - reproduction:

**Step 1**: Click on "All Categories" btn

Result: Dropdown is open

**Step 2**: Click again on "All Categories" btn - cus want to close dropdown

Result: As result Dropdown is open.

1. Clicked on "All categories" btn (state is changed isOpenAllCategories = true)

HERE is the problem --> 2. Click Again on "All Categories" btn

- First is called `handleOutsideClick()` function which sets `isOpenAllCategories on false`.
- Then is called `toggleAllCategories()` which change state on oposite of current value `isOpenAllCategories: !this.state.isOpenAllCategories` and that is `true` cus `handleOutsideClick()` already change state on `false`.

How have toggle dropdown on button click and close on outside click?

All Categories Dropdown component:

```
class AllCategories extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.handleClickOutside(e));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.handleClickOutside(e));
  }

  setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }

  handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.props.closeAllCategories();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="all-categories-wrapper">
        <div className="all-categories" ref={(node) => this.setWrapperRef(node)}>
          <ul className="all-categories-list">
            <li className="all-categories-list-item">All Categories</li>
            {this.state.allCategories.map((category) => (
              <li
                className={`all-categories-list-item ${
                  category.selected ? 'all-categories-list-item-active' : ''
                }`}
              >
                {category.name}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

All Categories Button component:

```
export default ({ toggleAllCategories, className }) => (
  <div className="category" onClick={() => toggleAllCategories()} role="button">
    <div className={`category-button-wrapper ${className}`}>
      <button className="category-button">
        Sports <span className="category-button-slash">/</span> Football
      </button>
      <div className="category-icon-box">
        <span className="category-icon">
          <i className="material-icons md-30 md-white">expand_more</i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code isn't working because of the scope of **this** in your component functions. You'll have to bind your functions in the constructor of your component. Or change your functions to ES6 which will solve the issue

```
//binding
constructor(props){
  super(props)
this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
}
handleClickOutside = () => {
 //code here
}
```

Comment: I bind like this: `this.setWrapperRef = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);` problem is cus now Outside click does not work.

Comment: Not like that. you have to bind in your contructor function.

Comment: Tried with that apporach now `this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);` It's work the same. Button does not toggle dropdown, and outside click works fine...

Comment: do the same bindings to all user-defined functions in the component and in your JSX remember to add this.toggleAllCategories() . you omitted this